# How to insert single line tabs into Flutter Quill Documents without full paragraph indents

Tags: flutter, quill

Using "\t" as would be standard elsewhere does not work giving an error icon and the default "indent" applies to entire paragraphs at a time unlike the behavior I intend as a tab for a paragraph like in Microsoft Word or Google Docs.

I have tried inserting '\t' and using Flutter Quill's built in indent system. I expect a tab result but instead can only achieve full paragraph indenting.

Flutter quill: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_quill